# Double arrow appeared on the select materialize

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I use materialize for my form page, but I have problem. I do not understand how the double arrow appeared on the select (see the photo I'm sending). How can one arrow be left?

[image]

I use this code:

```
<select name="filter" id="filter" onchange="parent.document.location.href=document.form.filter[document.form.filter.selectedIndex].value" required "/>
    <option value="" required "/>Одаберите начин плаћања</option>
    <option value="registracija1">1</option>
    <option value="registracija2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax of writing `select` element looks wrong as `"/` is not needed after `required`.

Also you have to include all the necessary resources (`css`, `js` library) of materialize and `javascript` code for `select` in your `html`. Else it will not work properly. Here's a working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select name="filter" id="filter" onchange="parent.document.location.href=document.form.filter[document.form.filter.selectedIndex].value" required>
  <option value="" required>Одаберите начин плаћања</option>
  <option value="registracija1">1</option>
  <option value="registracija2">2</option>
</select>
```